# Cannot load `Rails.config.active_storage.service`, missing required option :name - when running app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

After upgrading to Rails 5.2.2 and deploying to Heroku my app keeps crashing with this error. I have set my ENV variables in Heroku, including my RAILS_MASTER_KEY but nothing seems to be fixing it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
2019-01-28T21:23:20.220100+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.30.1/lib/aws-sdk-s3/bucket.rb:684:in `extract_name': Cannot load `Rails.config.active_storage.service`: (ArgumentError)
2019-01-28T21:23:20.220137+00:00 app[web.1]: missing required option :name
```

Comment: How did you set your `RAILS_MASTER_KEY ` variable on heroku?

Comment: under settings > config vars

Comment: can you remove that and try setting `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` using heroku cli?

`heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY="$(< config/master.key)"` run this command from the root directory of your application

Comment: @TonyVincent, the master.key is ignored in the gitignore file by default. I don't think the latter command will work on Heroku as a result of this.

Comment: @RT5754 its gitignored, thats why you neeed to run this locally using heroku cli

Comment: thank you so much this fixed it!!